# device-tree overlay: fragment numbers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

Consider the following device-tree overlay example.
The fragments are numbered 0, 1, 2.

Do the numbers matter?
Do they have to be in ascending order?
Or would 0, 2, 1 also work?
Where is it specified?

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    fragment@0 {
        target = <&foo>;
        __overlay__ {
            ...
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&bar>;
        __overlay__ {
            ...
        };
    };

    fragment@2 {
        target = <&baz>;
        __overlay__ {
            ...
        };
    };

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those numbers (and names) don't matter. Take a look at next functions in `drivers/of/overlay.c`:

[`of_overlay_create()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/of/overlay.c#L328) -> [`of_build_overlay_info()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/of/overlay.c#L251) -> [`of_fill_overlay_info()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/of/overlay.c#L216) -> [`find_target_node()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/of/overlay.c#L187)

As you can see, the code just iterates over the `tree` (using `for_each_child_of_node()`) and then obtaining node of interest by `"__overlay__"` name, like this:

```c
ovinfo->overlay = of_get_child_by_name(info_node, "__overlay__");
```

So those fragments are just some nodes, and their names don't matter. The only thing really used is content of those nodes.

I can even suppose that you can completely omit those `@1`, `@2` postfixes. Take a look at [Device Tree specification](http://elinux.org/images/c/cf/Power_ePAPR_APPROVED_v1.1.pdf) (section 2.2.1 Node Names):

> Each node in the device tree is named according to the following convention:

> `node-name@unit-address`

> The `unit-address` component of the name is specific to the bus type on which the node sits. It consists
> of one or more ASCII characters from the set of characters in Table 2-1. The `unit-address` must
> match the first address specified in the `reg` property of the node. **If the node has no `reg` property, the
> `@` and `unit-address` must be omitted and the node-name alone differentiates the node from other nodes
> at the same level in the tree**. The binding for a particular bus may specify additional, more specific
> requirements for the format of `reg` and the `unit-address`.

Of course, there can be some tricks in code that parses device tree file, like this: [drivers/of/fdt.c, unflatten_dt_node()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/of/fdt.c#L306):

```c
if ((*p1) == '@')
```

But I really doubt it that the number after '@' means something (in your case).